# Do Grails tests run in test environment by default?

Tags: grails, testing, grails-2.0

Is it necessary to supply the environment as `grails test test-app`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grails tests do run in the `test` environment by default.

In general Grails commands default to `dev` if not specified, but the `test-app` command overrides the environment to `test` if none was specified, and the `war` command defaults to `prod` if not specified.

Comment: Right, commands in general default to dev if not specified, but the test-app command overrides the env to test if none was specified, and the war target defaults to prod if not specified

Comment: @BurtBeckwith Added your comment(s) into the answer itself. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: `DEFAULT_ENVS` holds this.  see https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-bootstrap/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/cli/parsing/CommandLineParser.java#L43