# Getting uniqueness validation error while running grails integration testing on h2 with create-drop

Tags: grails, h2, grails-2.0

Every time I try to run an integration test I get an error that the bootstrap data is not unique for fields it's supposed to be unique. I was expecting the data from the past integration to be dropped an recreated.

One example is that the username for a user on my test data is not unique. It runs fine for the first time.

My datasource config for test looks like:

```
test {

    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "create-drop"
        url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;"
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I have now removed the bootstrap method that populated the data and my tests are passing(which apparently shouldn't)!

Comment: How do you run you tests? Are you sure you are using test environment?

Comment: @micha please take a look at my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25287173/do-grails-tests-run-in-test-environment-by-default